# Open a program within your java application

Tags: java

I think the correct term is "piping" but I hope someone will confirm/correct this.

Essentially, I would like to set my program to open up a file in a plotting program or text editor to be viewed (so I don't have to type it into the command line).

Is there a nice way of doing this? I have only opened and closed files so far so I am not sure where to start with opening them in a program.

Comment: What do you want the Java app to do?  Open a file and execute the contents of that file as a script or something?

Comment: I guess I would like it to execute a program in the same way that manually typing the program name and the file in the command line would.

Comment: you mean you want to inkoke your java app on the command line and give the command line an argument that is the name of a file that will be processed by your java program, so the command line would look like "myJavaApp theFileItWillProcess"

Comment: No, that's what I have been doing and getting tired of it so wanted a quick way to launch a graphing program once I had run my program. I got the answer though, cheers. I will try and think of a better way to reword this question anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class.

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad C:\boo.txt");

This will start the program "notepad" in a process, giving it the argument "C:\boo.txt" (which, for this example, will open that file using notepad). If all you want to do is start the program, you're done once you have this in. If you wish to play with command line input/output, you can use the process' streams eg:

> BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
>   PrintWriter stdOut = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());

The notepad example is Windows-specific, but the idea is the same in any case. The string passed to `exec()` will be run as if it were input on the command line for the OS on your machine.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I didn't realize it would be that simple! Will this work in java 6 too?

Comment: It will! I linked the 1.4 version by accident, but it's [still in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at AWT's [Desktop-Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) which can be used to open a program associated with a specific file type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process a file from your java program, you can simply give the path/name of the file to the Java program when you invoke it from the command line.  Note, when you execute a Java app:

```
java MyApp fileName true
```

Those args come in to your app as the arguments passed to the main method.

```
class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String nameOfFileOrSomething = args[0];
       String booleanForSomethingOrAnother = args[1];
    }
}
```

Is this what your after?

Comment: no, sorry but it is my fault for not being clear, I edited the question a bit to clarify. Sometimes it is hard to express what you need when you are not sure of the correct terminology!